# Powering buck converter using charged capacitor

Tags: capacitor, power-electronics, buck

[image]Is it possible to design a buck converter using a charged capacitor to get regulated voltage output? When the capacitor voltage falls below some threshold value the inductor should be able to provide output across the load resistance(during this time the source capacitor will be charged).

Comment: hmm. a buck converter with the roles of capacitors and inductors reversed. Good idea. Let me work out it's equations, but the first thing that comes to mind it that it will appear as a current source to the load.

Comment: The devil is in the detail and a more detailed "picture" is required explaining what you mean.

Comment: @Andyaka It would be a normal buck converter, just that instead of a DC Source there would be a charged capacitor. Initially the capacitor would be discharging to provide the output. When the capacitor output falls below some specified value it the output will be powered by the inductor. My doubt is whether i will get a regulated output voltage if i ensure Continuous Conduction Mode?

Comment: No, draw a sketch - clearly Abdullah reads it differently to me. It's the "powered by the inductor" thing that is all adrift.

Comment: In a buck converter, during the switch off time, the load is supplied only by the current in the inductor (until and unless it goes discontinuous) and the charge on the output capacitors.  Once your INPUT cap drops below a certain voltage you want to charge it during this off time, or as long as it takes to charge? And know if the inductor and caps can hold up your output voltage?  Depends on a whole bunch of things not included in the question.  Or am I missing the intent?

Comment: @Andyaka When the voltage Vs drops below some specified value, the switch will be opened and the capacitor will be charged until it reaches specified value. Then the switch will be closed and so on.

Comment: OK, so what's your load? You show no output caps but you need them to maintain voltage regulation.  What's the value of your inductor?  What's the value of your input cap?  How fast can you charge it?  What's your switching frequency?  At what voltage do you plan to recharge the cap?  What's your charge current?  What voltage do you plan to charge the cap to?  What's your target output voltage regulation point?  If you answer all those questions we might be able to tell you if it works or not.  Without, we can only say "it depends".

Comment: @JohnD I want to design the values so as to ensure Continuous Mode. I want to charge the capacitor during the off time. Yes, i want to know whether the inductor can give a regulated output voltage during this off time. Also how to calculate the duty ratio and time period of the switch so that a regulated output appears?

Comment: @JohnD i do not have any constraints regarding any values. I am trying to prove its working for the ideal case. Can u tell design criteria for calculating the values so that this would work. I just need a regulate output voltage.

Comment: You need an output capacitor to get anything like a regulated output voltage when the switch is open. The same is true of all buck converters and your circuit doesn't show one hence no, is the answer (within any reasonable guess). When the switch is open, the input capacitor can re-charge - that's a also a given for all buck converters.

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry, i forgot to  the draw the capacitor. If the capacitor is there will it work?

Comment: No, it won't likely work without you stating much more detail as per what JohnD says.

Comment: @JohnD  Load 1000ohm, input capacitor 1 micro and charging time is 1.4 sec. Capacitor will charge to 21 V and discharges till 19.8V. I need 3.3 V regulated output voltage. These are the constraints. My doubt is in deciding what values to use for inductor, switching time and output capacitor so that all these conditions are satisfied.

Comment: By my calculations you have 24.5 uJ of energy from the cap (21V-19.8V).  You could deliver maybe 21 uJ to the load which will run your 1K load @3.3V for just under 2 ms.  If your cap takes 1.4s to charge I think you have a problem of several orders of magnitude.

Comment: I encourage you to study all aspects of your circuit by completing the circuit and making all necessary calculation and then simulations so you can test the performance in different contexts to see where  this converter is better if it is. If you have an idea don't let it go like this. And if you get nothing at least you will have the chance to enhance your knowledge in switching power supply by getting deeper into it.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, of course it is.

In a buck converter, the switch (you have drawn) opens and closes at a certain rate and duty cycle. Current is only consumed from the input (capacitor) during the on-time of this switch. What happens during the off-time is irrelevant, and you could use that to recharge the capacitor.

This is not necessarily a good idea; you need additional switches, and in most circumstances, it doesn't perform any better than just leaving the input voltage source permanently attached.